# jpa project with wampserver cant put anything to DB

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jpa, wampserver

I've created a database and added the employee table with the following code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
  `Idemployee` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fIrstname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emaIl` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- 
--

INSERT INTO `employee` (`Idemployee`, `fIrstname`, `lastname`, `emaIl`) VALUES
(2, 'Pranil', 'kharkar', 'someMail@gmail.com'),
(5, 'prasad', 'kharkar', 'someMail@gmail.com'),
(8, 'prasad', 'kharkar', 'someMail@gmail.com'),
(9, 'prasad', 'kharkar', 'someMail@gmail.com'),
(10, 'Pranil', 'kharkar', 'someMail@gmail.com'),
(11, 'Pranil', 'kharkar', 'someMail@gmail.com'),
(13, 'prasad', 'kharkar', 'someMail@gmail.com'),
(14, 'prasad', 'kharkar', 'someMail@gmail.com'),
(15, 'Murat', 'Kandemir', 'cmkTurkiye@gmail.com'),
(16, 'Murat2', 'Kandemir2', 'cmkTurkiye@gmail.com');

--
--

--
--
ALTER TABLE `employee`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Idemployee`);

--
-- 
--

--
--
--
ALTER TABLE `employee`
  MODIFY `Idemployee` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=17;
```

and then created jpa project and created these 2 code pieces below for adding someone to table;

```
package com.thejavageek.jpa;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.thejavageek.jpa.entities.Employee;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

        /* Create EntityManagerFactory */
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("kurumsaljava");

        /* Create and populate Entity */
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setFirstname("Ahmet");
        employee.setLastname("Mercan");
        employee.setEmail("cmkTurkiye@gmail.com");
        //employee.setIdEmployee();

        /* Create EntityManager */
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        /* Persist entity */
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(employee);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        /* CMK UPDATE
         */
        /* Update routines begin*/
        /*
        int iEdit = 0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter Employee Number To Edit");
        //String iEdit = br.readLine();

        try{
            iEdit = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            System.err.println("Invalid Format!");
        }
        employee = em.find(Employee.class, iEdit);
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        employee.setFirstname("Murat7");
        employee.setLastname("Celal");
        System.out.println("Employee after updation :- " + employee);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        */
        /*Update routines finish*/

        // CMK DELETE
        /* Delete routines begin*/
        /*
        int iRemove = 0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter Employee Number To Remove");
        try{
            iRemove = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            System.err.println("Invalid Format!");
        }
        // Remove entity 
        employee = em.find(Employee.class, iRemove);
        System.out.println(employee);
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(employee);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        */
        /*Delete routines finish*/

        /* CMK
         */ 

        /* Retrieve entity */
        /*
        employee = em.find(Employee.class, iEdit);
        System.out.println(employee);
        */

        /* Check whether entity is removed or not */
        /*employee = em.find(Employee.class, 1);
        System.out.println("Employee after removal :- " + employee);*/

    }
}
```

and Employee.java;

package com.thejavageek.jpa.entities;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Employee
 *
 */
@Entity

public class Employee implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6984979000774926570L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idEmployee;

    private String email;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public int getIdEmployee() {
        return this.idEmployee;
    }

    public void setIdEmployee(int IdEmployee) {
        this.idEmployee = IdEmployee;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [email=" + email
                + ", firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + "]";
    }

}
```

and persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="kurumsaljava">
        <class>com.thejavageek.jpa.entities.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kurumsaljava?useSSL=false" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

database name is kurumsaljava.I am getting these errors couldnt solve them

```
[EL Warning]: 2016-04-27 15:45:04.913--UnitOfWork(1576499395)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?L, F?RSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES ('cmkTurkiye@gmail.com', 'Ahmet', 'Mercan')' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (EMAİL, FİRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Employee [email=cmkTurkiye@gmail.com, firstname=Ahmet, lastname=Mercan])
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?L, F?RSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES ('cmkTurkiye@gmail.com', 'Ahmet', 'Mercan')' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (EMAİL, FİRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Employee [email=cmkTurkiye@gmail.com, firstname=Ahmet, lastname=Mercan])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
    at com.thejavageek.jpa.Test.main(Test.java:35)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?L, F?RSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES ('cmkTurkiye@gmail.com', 'Ahmet', 'Mercan')' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (EMAİL, FİRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Employee [email=cmkTurkiye@gmail.com, firstname=Ahmet, lastname=Mercan])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?L, F?RSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES ('cmkTurkiye@gmail.com', 'Ahmet', 'Mercan')' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:890)
    ... 32 more
```

waiting for your answers.

Comment: You have seen the SQL syntax errors in that dump i assume??

Comment: You do also know that MYSQL column names are CASE SENSITIVE and you have used some rather strange capitalisation in the column names when you created the table, but not in the queries

Comment: Should I assume you can fix this yourself now?

Comment: No reply for ages, its a typo anyway I suggest closing it as such

Comment: I am realy sory i was pretty busy with my other classes,so you are saying problem is in my queries

Comment: ow it worked thank you for you support :)

Answer (score 0):

As RiggsFolly said above i changed the Employee class's this parts i's to I;

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [email=" + email
                + ", firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + "]";
    }

}
```

and added some addition to persistence.xml's connection string;

```
localhost:3306/example?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useSSL=false
```

and it is working thx